# How to get width of svelte component

Tags: binding, width, svelte

I want to store the width of a parent component and pass it down to its child component in `<slot />`:

```
<Parent bind:clientWidth={width}>
   <Child width={width}></Child>
</Parent>
```

I know that I can use `bind:clientWidth` on a normal html element like this:

```
<div bind:clientWidth={width}></div>
```

But for some reason this does not work with a svelte component:

```
<Component bind:clientWidth={width}></Component>
```

How can I get the parent width? Maybe there's a solution that doesn't involve declaring a separate variable to pass down to the child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Components can be completely empty and contain multiple elements without a wrapper, they have no intrinsic size.

If you have control over the implementation of the parent, you could internally get the size of some element and pass it as a [slot property](https://svelte.dev/docs/special-elements#slot-slot-key-value). Or you could add a wrapper element and use that to measure.

Cannot think of a way to circumvent having an additional variable *somewhere*.